# looking for exact match?

Tags: search, formula

1The column present in A column exist as qtkyusvdgmzhz15mkkba
and b column exists as qtkyusvdgmzhz15mkkba.jpg but I need to check whether two columns are same spelling without .jpg can you please tell me about this ??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3; B3))
```

Where

`A3`: qtkyusvdgmzhz15mkkba

`B3`: qtkyusvdgmzhz15mkkba.jpg

The statment is TRUE if `A3` exists in `B3` somewhere. Remember spaces " " counts too in your search word (`A3`).

Comment: that would give false positive in case A3 = "qtkyusvdgmzhz15mkkba" and B3 = "XXXqtkyusvdgmzhz15mkkba.jpg"

Comment: yes it would give TRUE. My interpretation looking at the example data, the word can be in the middle and I guess the ending can differ too (gif, jpeg, jpg etc..)... Given that the ending always is the same, your approach is better :)

Comment: I saw your other post, try this to replace the `A3` in cell `B3`. `=REPLACE(A1;SEARCH(A1;B1);;)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
=A3=MID(B3,SEARCH("/",B3)+1,SEARCH(".",B3)-(SEARCH("/",B3)+1))
```

[image]

Comment: yeah its work but the problem was in A column qqowwebnroexacwnm2zd
in B column v1529320301/qqowwebnroexacwnm2zd.jpg its execute as FALSE

Comment: this condition doesn't resolve v1529320301/qqowwebnroexacwnm2zd.jpg and the condition should be resolved as qqowwebnroexacwnm2zd.jpg,v1529320301/qqowwebnroexacwnm2zd.jpg and https://res.cloudinary.com/du8msdgbj/image/upload/s--l_wfpMsL--/a_ignore,w_120,h_120,c_fit,q_auto,f_auto/bctc2fjg25mxvnjj0bak.png

Comment: I tested and it actually outcomes `True` for `qqowwebnroexacwnm2zd ` in A3 and `v1529320301/qqowwebnroexacwnm2zd.jpg` in B3

Comment: its comes as #VALUE

Comment: you must be doing something wrong (see image in edited answer)